# JQuery autocomplete list disappear

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, triggers, jquery-autocomplete

When I try to select one of the elements in my autocomplete list the whole list disappears! It happens once I try the move the mouse inside the dropdown list.

My autocomplete:

[image]

The `js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` is included, the same as `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.less`.

Any ideas?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="region_box" name="region_box">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<%$(language.placeholder.search_box.%b__lang)%>" id="yourCity" size="35" maxlength="50" style="width:340px;" tabindex="1">
<input id="chooseb_auto" class="choose" value="&translate("SEARCHBOX_CHOOSE_BUTTON")" type="submit">
<div class="error_label">
```

...

JS code:

```
// Choose the city button 
var both = 0;
$(".choose").live("click",function(){
    for (var id in regionArray) {
        if( trim(regionArray[id].name[lang]).toUpperCase() == trim($("#yourCity").val()).toUpperCase() ) {
            otherRegionChoosen(id);
            window.LightBox.close();
            return;
        }
    }
..
```

PS: I have the same autocomplete in other pages on the website and it's working, but on the landing page it doesn't

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS code.

Comment: Without showing your code, its not possible somebody will point out the issue. It does work as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/

Comment: @AamirAfridi Sorry, I just post it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Done! sorry

Answer (score 0):

if you are using latest jquery version you have to be very clear on

**.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) { };** in this line.

here we will do mistake is **"autocomplete"**..... In **JQuery higher versions** we have to

give like **.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {};**

for you i share some snippet....PLease find it and if you have any problem feel free me to ask .. Happy Coding!!!!!!

I think you got it what i am telling.....

$('#ID_YourElement').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {

```
                var URL = '';

                URL = "yourServiceURL";


                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data2) {
                        response($.map(data2, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName,
                                value: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName,
                                Data: item
                            }
                        }));


                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                $(this).attr("Data", JSON.stringify(ui.item.Data));

                uiResult.push(ui.item.Data);


            },
             open: function (event, ui) {
                if ($('.ui-autocomplete').find('li').length > 3) {
                    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('padding-right', '20px').css('width', '340px').css('max-height', '225px').css('overflow-y', 'auto').addClass('dropdown-menu');
                }
                else {
                    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('padding-right', '2px').css('width', '340px').css('max-height', '225px').css('overflow-y', 'auto').addClass('dropdown-menu');
                }
                $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();
                $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 100000);

                return false;
            }
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

            var html = '';

            html = html + '<a href="javascript:;" tabindex="-1">';

            html = html + '<div style="font-weight: 600;" class="span10">';
            html = html + '<span>' + item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + '</span><br>';
            html = html + '<span>' + item.Email + '</span>';
            html = html + '</div>';

            html = html + '</a>';



            return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(html).appendTo(ul);
        };
```